# Oracle 12cR2 - How To Create DDL Script Of A View With All Dependencies and Permissions

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, view, ddl

I have a view in my production database and I want to create same view in my test database.

I tried this commmand:

```
‌‌select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW','VIEW_NAME','VIEW_OWNER') from dual;
```

It generated a create script and I run it. But it didn't copy all of the dependencies, data types, etc.

How can I do this?

Regards,

Comment: I usually run `git checkout` at the command prompt. If you are using SQLDeveloper,  use the Cart feature.

Answer (score 0):

That would require selecting from dba_dependencies. Since your dependencies may have their own dependencies that query would probably need to be recursive.

Also, if any of the dependencies are in a different schema then you'll also need the grants to go with them which you can get by selecting from dba_tab_privs and dba_col_privs.